# Recommendations for c++ web programming frameworks that do not use .net

Tags: c++

There are obviously a lot of different choices out there if you want to program for the web using Java.  Does anybody have recommendations for someone who wants a free software framework for web programming?  I want to work on Linux, and I would prefer to avoid .net/mono.

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/746309/which-is-the-best-c-web-framework

Comment: Do you have any special reason why to choose C++? Like performance issues, already existing C++ libraries and infrastructure etc.

Comment: @Ken: figured it was a dup, thanks.

Comment: @Messa: both performance issues and already existing libraries (which go hand-in-hand for this application).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- [Cgicc](http://www.gnu.org/software/cgicc/)
- [Wt](http://www.webtoolkit.eu/wt)
- [CppCMS](http://cppcms.sourceforge.net/wikipp/en/page/main)

Comment: Note, Cgicc is rather small and limited CGI library then full framework.

Comment: @Artyom: thanks, this is exactly the sort of color I am looking for.

Answer (score -1):

My recommendation is not to do web programming in C++. Try any of Django (python), Ruby on Rails, PHP, or even Perl. There's plenty to choose from.

Comment: I have reasons for choosing C++ over other languages, which is why I specifically asked about C++.